# In C#, how can I make a parameterized constructor set up variables first

Tags: c#

Here is the code I have:

```
namespace Templates
{

    public class ArrowGrid : BaseGrid
    {

        public ArrowGrid(string a, string b) : this()
        {
            IconSource = a;
            IconBackgroundColor = b;
        }

        public ArrowGrid()
        {
            var xx = new XX(a,b);
```

I understand that the calling order is:

```
a) this()
b) the ArrowGrid empty constructor
c) the lines with IconSource = a
```

Is there a way that the IconSource = a could be set before the line `var a = new XX(a,b);`

Comment: You might consider reversing the relationship between constructors - have the one which accepts the most parameters perform the full construction logic, and constructors with fewer parameters provide suitable default(s).

Comment: What Damien said: having `public ArrowGrid() : this(null,null)` for example

Comment: Can you explain why you need the default constructor, when your parameterised one appears to do all of the work?

Comment: @ChrisBD: Not OP but in general, the ability to call something while giving it less information (= less parameters than in use) is simply another way of phrasing that you want to allow for some default values to be used. Commonly used framework methods tend to be mostly used _without_ specifying every possible parameter, specifically because the defaults are most commonly the correct choice. OP's example seems no different here.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - A question I have in regards to your suggestion which sounds very good.  If the new constructor with method and code takes the parameters then should I be calling the base constructor in BaseGrid?  Could you also give an example so that others who see the question can also see your answer.

Comment: @Flater. Understood. Wouldn't it be clearer to use `public ArrowGrid(string a="default string a", string b="default string b"){ ... }`

Comment: @ChrisBD: It depends. This opens the door to having one specified and one default value, which may not be desirable. I also think you're going to run into issues when dealing with consumers that expect to find a parameterless constructor (e.g. serializers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Damien_The_Unbeliever is correct in his comment, you should reverse your constructor relationship.

The first thing I wondered when looking at your code is whether you were expecting the parameterless constructor to be called by itself. The main takeaway here is that you either didn't (and then your setup is not good), or you did and you have some default values for `a` and `b` in mind (maybe null, maybe something predefined).

If you don't want the parameterless constructor to be called by itself, it simply shouldn't exist. So your solution is to only have one constructor:

```
public ArrowGrid(string a, string b)
{
    IconSource = a;
    IconBackgroundColor = b;

    var xx = new XX(a,b);
}
```

If you do want the parameterless constructor to be called by itself, but you want it to depend on the parametered constructor, then set up the relation in that way. Instead of the parametered constructor calling the parameterless one, do it the other way around.

```
public class ArrowGrid
{
    private string a;
    private string b;

    public ArrowGrid(string a, string b)
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.a = b;

        IconSource = a;
        IconBackgroundColor = b;
    }

    public ArrowGrid() : this("default_for_a", "default_for_b")
    {
        var xx = new XX(a,b);
    }
}
```

When you now call `new ArrowGrid()`, it will behind the scenes first perform `new ArrowGrid("default_for_a", "default_for_b")` and then continue with whatever logic you put in the `ArrowGrid()` constructor.

Some notes:

- Unfortunately, you can't just store the default string value in the `a` and `b` class fields directly, since you can't reference `this.a` or `this.b` in the `this( , )` constructor call. I'm surprised the language doesn't allow for this, but I understand why it is the way it is.
- You could forego the `a` and `b` class fields entirely, and do `new XX(this.IconSource, this.IconBackgroundColor)`. But whether or not using those different names is appropriate is contextual and I can't make a final judgment on this.
- If I'm wrong and you *don't* want to have default values for these strings, then your approach can't possibly be correct (since a parameterless constructor inherently relies on default values being used), and then the first solution (merging the constructors to force the string values being passed) applies.

Comment: You mention about not calling the parameterless constructor.  But I still need the BaseGrid constructor to be called.  Can you add some notes relating to that if you feel what I am saying makes sense. Note that I don't need the BaseGrid constructor to be called with any arguments. Thanks

Comment: @iamsophia: Your question didn't mention the `BaseGrid` constructor so I couldn't really account for it. Regardless, whichever constructor is guaranteed to be called (the parametered one in my example) should then chain through to the `BaseGrid` constructor of your choice, i.e. `public ArrowGrid(string a, string b) : base()`. Note that in cases where you want your two `ArrowGrid` constructors to each reference a different `BaseGrid` constructor, then you inherently can't daisychain your two `ArrowGrid` constructors to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly. You can, however, extract the code of your parameterless constructor into a separate method and call that method *instead of* `: this()`:

```
    public ArrowGrid(string a, string b)
    {
        IconSource = a;
        IconBackgroundColor = b;
        InitializeStuff();
    }

    public ArrowGrid()
    {
        InitializeStuff();
    }

    private void InitializeStuff()
    {
        var xx = new XX(a,b);
        ...
    }
```

Do note, though, that calling instance methods in the constructor is generally discouraged, since the object might not be fully initialized yet. Thus, use this technique with care.

Comment: While this solution isn't wrong in the sense that it still compiles and does what it says on the tin, it has effectively removed the reusable nature of the constructors and needlessly migrated the reusability to an arbitrary method instead. It's (IMHO) not an improvement over doing it with constructors due to the lowered readability. The claim that it can't be done any other way is also not correct, by the way.

Comment: @flater - Could you explain or suggest an alternative.  I realize it's not such a simple thing but I really would like to do it in the best way possible.  Thank you.

Comment: @iamsophia: It wasn't my intention to self-promote my answer on the back of this one (I find it cheap), but I did post an answer of my own already with an alternative approach.

Comment: @Flater: Don't worry, I don't consider your criticism as self-promotion, and I think your answer is useful. However, ...

Comment: ...  I still stand by my claim that doing what the OP asked---executing custom constructor-specific code before calling a parameterless constructor---is not possible *directly* in C# (and hacks such as `: this(someMethod())` don't apply to parameterless constructors). Your code is not a counter-example, it's another (very valid and useful!) way to solve the OP's *underlying* problem, with its own advantages and drawbacks (e.g. the additional assignment to `IconSource` and `IconBackgroundColor` in the case of the parameterless constructor).